# Does PowerCenter have a C# Transformation?

Tags: c#, etl, informatica, informatica-powercenter

I'm evaluating Informatica PowerCenter as a replacement for our SSIS ETL packages.  We're a C# shop and thus we'd like the ability to run C# code in our transformations.  I see that PowerCenter comes with a Java transformation.  Is there a way to have a C# transformation?

*I'm using the trial PowerCenter Express*

Comment: AFAIK you cannot run C# code in Informatica transformations. However, you might find some way to call your C# programs from Java.

Answer (score 0):

According to this post https://community.informatica.com/thread/49508 : probably not. Question of OP is same as on that informatica forum.

So no, thhough there is an option: to program a Custom Transformation in C to be used to interact with C#.

But, as Nico Heinze says on Jan 31, 2015 2:16 PM (in response to Jordan Robinson):
"(...)
Calling a SQL Transformation means data movement between PowerCenter and DBMS; then the DBMS must perform a context switch to the SP; the SP must open a new process; this process starts a batch file (which is never fast by nature), and the batch file starts a C# program.

No offense intended, but even I will need some time to think of any approach which is not even more complicated and can kill performance as well as this idea.

Again, no offense intended, but this is extremely complicated, far more complicated than necessary. Calling the C# program via a small Java Transformation probably will still be faster, and this is not performing too well either."